# Get one to may relationship data from tables as JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

[image]

I have this two tables from the diagrams.For every question i can have multiple answer.
I want to get data by question id in json format like this:

```
var initialData = [
    {question_id: "1", Description: "Danny", Status: "1", answers: [
        { answer_id: "1", description: "AAAAA" },
        { answer_id: "2", description: "Bbbbb" }]
    }
];
```

I use this code

```
  var question = db.Questions.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.questionID== id);
  return this.Json(question , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and i get this

```
var initialData = [
        {question_id: "1", Description: "Danny", Status: "1", answers:null

        }
    ];
```

Can you help my please with a solution.

Comment: likely because the collection is lazily loaded. Make sure your `answers` collection is materialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this please.

```
var question = db.Questions.Include("Answer").FirstOrDefault((p) => p.questionID== id);
```

Have a look at the ado.Net [blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232)